# How to protect an IOT device from clones

Tags: security

I have a physical IOT device with an ePROM in it that contains a unique serial number (userID) and generated random password.  it connects via sFTP and http services to our server, using these credentials.

I figure we can use Diffie-Hellman to protect ourselves from impostors who lack physical access to our devices, from sending false data and getting free service charged to someone else.

But because our devices are "in the wild" it might be easy for some one to get physical access to one our units and clone our ePROM.

My question is what is the best way to protect ourselves from such attacks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need something like the TPM module in Lenovo laptops. It is a small hardware module that can store a private key, and you cannot get the key once it is written. This way you could write the private key to the TPM, then deploy it, and nobody would be able to impersonate. They would be able to change the private key, but then you would notice since the public key would not match.

Now, I am not sure how costly such a module is, and I am not sure about extra battery cost, but this would secure your device.